# How to make jwplayer to work with Polymer 2

Tags: jwplayer, polymer-2.x

I'm using Polymer 2, and jwplayer (video player)
When I create instance of jwplayer, I should give it id of container. Like this

```
jwplayer("container_id").setup({...})
```

But because of shadow dom, jwplayer cannot find element with id, even it exists, because it's in shadow dom.
In polymer I think we should use like this:

```
Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector()
```

But external libraries do not do like this.
**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
jwplayer(this.$.container_id).setup({...})
```

Ref. https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer/blob/master/src/js/jwplayer.js#L34-L37

Comment: I tried jwplayer(this.$.container_id),  but it is not working

Comment: What error did you get? Can you setup a test case on https://plnkr.co or https://github.com?